# Styling custom control

Tags: c#, wpf

I made my own controls.  One inherits from `DataGrid` and the another from `ContentControl`. One of them gets the other so I try to expose their properties but as I need many different controls I want to make a Style for my control (the one that inherit from `DataGrid`) and set the properties from this control to my `ContentControl`. I just wrote the code like this but it does not work. Any body knows what I am doing wrong?

```
<Style x:Key="CustomDataGridStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomDataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="CurrentRow"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:DataGridContainer}}, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="CaptionVisibility"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:DataGridContainer}}, Path=CaptionVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="CaptionText"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:DataGridContainer}}, Path=CaptionText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="RowValidationErrorTemplate"
            Value="{StaticResource BasicRowValidationErrorTemplate}" />
    <Setter Property="CurrentView"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:DataGridContainer}}, Path=CurrentView, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    <Setter Property="CurrentColumnHeaderText"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:DataGridContainer}}, Path=CurrentColumnHeader, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedCellText"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:DataGridContainer}}, Path=SelectedText, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    <Setter Property="IsDataGridFocused"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:DataGridContainer}}, Path=HasFocus, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
</Style>
```

And I have defined my control like this

```
<controls:CustomDataGrid x:Key="DataGridOne" AutoGenerateColumns="True" x:Shared="False" ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

and the another one

```
<controls:DataGridContainer Content="{StaticResource DataGridOne}" DataContext="{Binding Products}" 
                                            x:Name="dataGridOne" SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                        Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" CaptionVisibility="Collapsed"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style has x:Key attribute set. This means it won't apply to all controls of that type by-default. You should either remove the Key attribute to make the style default and apply to all CustomDataGrid controls, or reference Style in the CustomDataGrid definition like this:

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomDataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomDataGrid}">
     ...
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>

 <controls:CustomDataGrid ... Style="{StaticResource CustomDataGridStyle}" ... />
</Window>
```

Comment: I already try that. And I have defined my CustomDataGrid also as a Resource do you think it is my problem ? I cannot assign an Style to a other control inside my resource ?

Comment: Create a setter with no binding but a simple value. Check if this works. The problem may be a different than you think it is.

Comment: I try with something like this ``<Style x:Key="CustomDataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type controls:RaceUIDataGrid}"> <Setter Property="IsDataGridReadOnly" Value="True"/> </Style>`` and works, but what I need is to expose the properties from CustomDataGrid to DataGridContainer

Comment: This cannot be posible :(. I had a bad approach of what I was doing. The setter is just for set a variable with a value is not for give it references